# Sentiment_by function

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis, sentimentr

i am collecting the sentiment data of some twitter information. Moreover I have been using the function sentiment_by in order to group the information by a column.

```
sent<-sentiment_by(tidy_libros_stopwords$word, by=tidy_libros_stopwords$screen_name)
```

[image]
The problem that now I need to group by two columns (screen_name and created_at) I have tried this but doesn't work

```
sent<-sentiment_by(tidy_libros_stopwords$word, by=tidy_libros_stopwords$screen_name,tidy_libros_stopwords$created_at)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `by` argument expects a list if more than one grouping variable is provided. Try this:

```
sent<-sentiment_by(tidy_libros_stopwords$word, by=list(tidy_libros_stopwords$screen_name,tidy_libros_stopwords$created_at))
```